# Azure Blob lease expired right after renewal

Tags: azure-blob-storage

I am working with an Azure Blob and the code had been working and is not now.  I get an error 412 saying that the lease ID is included but the lease has expired.  I am renewing the lease just prior to uploading the file so I am not sure why it is expired.  The file is 3-4 MB in size.  What could be causing this and how do I fix it.

```
       using (var memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
        {

            AccessCondition acc = new AccessCondition();
            acc.LeaseId = blobLease;
            blockBlob.RenewLease(acc);
            dataSet1.WriteXml(memoryStream);
            string newDataHash = GetHash(memoryStream);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Old Data Hash {0}",originalDataHash);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("New Data Hash {0}",newDataHash);
            if (newDataHash != originalDataHash)
                {

                    memoryStream.Position = 0;
                try
                {
                    blockBlob.UploadFromStream(memoryStream, acc);

                }
                catch (StorageException ex)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(ex.Message);
                    count = 15;
                    timer1_Tick(this, e);
                }
                originalDataHash = GetHash(memoryStream);
                }
            else

            {
                //if data hasn't changed in 15 minutes let lease expire so someone else can use the blob,  try to obtain new lease when the user comes back   
                if (count >= 15)
                {
                    count = 0;
                    timer1.Stop();
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Attempting to renew Expired Lease");
                    awaitNewLease(this, e);

                }
            }
            count = 0;


        }
```

Comment: what is the exact error message you are getting ? 
Could you add it to your question ?

Comment: Was the provided answer helpful to your question ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend including the FetchAttributes method to get details about the lease, these should let you know what the issue is:

```
    //cloudBlockBlob is a reference to a CloudBlockBlob
TimeSpan? leaseTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
string leaseID = cloudBlockBlob.AcquireLease(leaseTime, null);

//wait until the lease has expired before continuing
AccessCondition acc = new AccessCondition();
acc.LeaseId = leaseID;
cloudBlockBlob.RenewLease(acc);

cloudBlockBlob.FetchAttributes();
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("LeaseDuration = {0}", cloudBlockBlob.Properties.LeaseDuration);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("LeaseState = {0}", cloudBlockBlob.Properties.LeaseState);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("LeaseStatus = {0}", cloudBlockBlob.Properties.LeaseStatus);
```

I'd also recommend the review of the following detailed [**documentation**](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/cloud/platform-as-a-service/azure-blob-storage-part-8-blob-leases/) on Leasing blobs, which might help in your implementation.